# Set focus EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, lost-focus

I have a problem with EditText, in my app I need codebars that get it with codebar scanner, when the CCBB was inserted in the ET, the focus go to a ListView, but i tried to return the focus with:

> et.requestFocus();

But the focus not move of the listview, also tried with disable focus of the listview.

In the app I have a thread with TTS, that speak every 15s and I put the  et.requestFocus() in the thread but it dosn't work.

thanks!

---

I have achieved it with this code in xml:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/ccbb"
        android:id="@+id/codigobarra"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/codigobarra"/>
```

Comment: have you set android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"?

Comment: Are you use requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); if it is there remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will help you.

```
listview.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      et.requestFocus();
      et.setFocusable(true);
      et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` property to parent view of your listItem and in `EditText`  `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` like below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        tools:context="com.cj.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Name" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it, but it does not work. The focus chanched again.

Comment: you can change edittext focus to  android:focusable="false"

Comment: if change edittext to android:focusable="false", I can't insert the codebar in the edittext.

Comment: I make it with: android:nextFocusRight="@id/edittext" in xml.

Thanks

Comment: if your layout has multipal EditText  then you may use this to change focus  through this other wise no need to add this .